# query to count students

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

```
Table - Class
=========================

id | name 

1  | class 1

2  | class 2
```

```
Table - Teachers
=========================

id | name 

1  | Teacher 1

2  | Teacher 2
```

```
Table - class-Teacher
=========================

id | teacher_id | class_id 

1  |     1      |   1

2  |     1      |   2
```

```
Table - students
=========================

id |   name     | class_id 

1  |  student 1 |   1

2  |  student 2 |   2
```

**Expecting Result**

```
 id  |     name       | total_students

  1  |  Teacher 1     |    2

  2  |  Teacher 2     |    0
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `left join`s and aggregation:

```
select t.id, t.name, count(s.id) no_students
from teachers t
left join class_teachers ct on ct.teacher_id = t.id
left join students s on s.class_id = ct.class_id
group by t.id, t.name
```